# Pegar imagem no banco de dados

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

queria saber como eu poderia recuperar uma imagem do banco de dados, usado o php7, a imagem esta gravada no banco de dados no tipo BLOB, pesquisei na internet e eram exemplos muito antigos e nenhum funcionou aqui, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para inserir a imagem faça o seguinte:**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
$query = "INSERT INTO products (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  
$qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

**Para acessar a imagem de Blob**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Espero que funcione para você!

Comment: Exatamente assim mesmo.

Comment: Vou testar aqui, e trago o feedback para você.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara deu certinho !